# Multidimensional Spring Profiles for prod/test vs gui

Tags: spring, user-interface, testing, production, spring-profiles

I am new to Spring and I never used profiles.
I want to develop an application and set up different logic for different environments.
I need a production environment and a test environment, for both I should be able to define if the GUI is active or not.
I have then 4 compiles: 
- Prod with GUI
- Prod with NO GUI
- Test with GUI
- Test with NO GUI

Can you provide some examples or documentation on how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although the concept is not hard to grasp, you won't be able to understand Spring Profiles right away if you are completely new to Spring.

The documentation has been recently revamped so I'd start here: [the Core Spring Framework Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core).

After you grasp the Spring basics (bean lifecycle / dependency injection / configuration / properties) I'd focus on the [Profiles part of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles).

I also suggest the [Spring Boot sample project about Profiles showcasing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-profile) that you could `git clone` right away and experiment with, even though you might not understand all the details.

Comment: I was able to create profiles and inject different beans and configurations depending on the different environment.

Comment: Now I need an example on how to create two application versions one with GUI and one without GUI depending on the profile "UI" or "nonUI"